# How to find the record with max field value

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am querying MongoDB using C# for log records, I have figured out that the new  .NET v2 driver does not have the same api as the older legacy one.  Still have not figured out how to query for a max value.

```
{ 
    { "user" , user },
    { "message" , message },
    { "dt" , EpochTimeStamp }
}
```

The timestamp is a unix Epoch (the number of seconds since 1972 ...) so it's a positive whole integer.

I would like to find the most recent record (the one with max value of "dt"") by querying the database (this would be easy in SQL)

```
public async void selectMostRecent(IMongoDatabase _database)
{
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("conversations");

    //this kind of filter works well and gives me all records 'from' a given time stamp
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt("dt", from);
    var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

//BUT.....

    //How do I create a filter or a sort to return the record with max value of dt?
    var RecordwitMaxDT = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(???)

    //I've tried this sort, and variations but I cant get it to run.  
    var RecordwitMaxDT = col.Find<BsonDocument>("{}").SortByDescending("{dt}").SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the solution to my question

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort;
var sort = builder.Descending("dt");
var CursorToResults =  col.Find<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument()).Sort(sort);
var RecordwithMax_dt_Value = await CursorToResults.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The issue was that there is a new driver for .NET with a new api, all the solutions on the web are obsolete.

Key lessons learned include a) creating a builder of subtype sort, b) pre-defining the sort to be injected into the find and c) needing an empty BsonDocument in the Find to 'select all records', it's effectively a blank filter.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way performance wise but you could try:

```
var result = collection.OrderByDescending(m => m.YourTimeStampColumn).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That gives me this error .. I did check that have the mongodb driver and the bson  library installed, so  ... ??? 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have `System.Linq` referenced in your file?

Comment: System.Linq should give you the necessary reference as krillgar stated. Linq is a language that permits you to query collections in this case your MongoDB collection.